# What is the difference between these 2 object arrays?

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-chrome, console.log

The first array is created pushing two objects to the array, the second is created by initiating it with the two objects.

```
const data = [{
          name: 'Microsoft Internet Explorer',
          y: 56.33
        }, {
          name: 'Chrome',
          y: 24.03
        }];
```

[image: Object Arrays]

Comment: it just says "value below was evaluated just now"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no difference in the objects. The difference is that you did `console.log(data)` of the first array before you filled it in, so the first line shows the empty array. But console output is "live", it's connected to the object. So when you click on it to expand it, you see the current contents.